# How to show that the set $Z(G)=\{z \in G : \forall g \in G, z * g = g * z\}$ is a subgroup of $(G, *)$?

Tags: group-theory

I have shown that the neutral element is in $Z(G)$. I have also shown that the law is closed in $Z(G)$.

However, I'm not sure how to prove that $\forall x \in Z(G), \exists x' \in Z(G)$ such that $x * x' = x' * x = e$, where $e$ is the neutral element.

I would like to post what I've tried so far, but everything I think of immediately leads to a dead end. How do I go about solving this? Also, we don't know if $G$ is a commutative group. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're phrasing it as though you want to prove that $Z(G)$ is a group, not that it is a subgroup of $G$. This distinction is technically just fiction, but the thought process changes a bit: you *know* that $x'$ exists as an element of $G$. The only thing you need to show is that it is also contained in $Z(G)$.

In other words, you need to show that if $xg=gx$ for all $g\in G$, then $x'g=gx'$ for all $g\in G$ as well. One way to show this is by
$$
x'g=x'ge\\
=x'gxx'\\
=x'xgx'\\
=egx'=gx'
$$

Comment: Ah of course. I honestly wouldn't have thought of that. Couldn't I do this for any element, meaning that G = Z(G), and thus G is a commutative group? Or is that way off?

Comment: @user494405 No, you can't do this for any element. Note the equality $x'gxx'=x'xgx'$, which relies on $xg=gx$.

Comment: Oh. Of course; I'm stupid. Apart from that though, would this make the sub-group a commutative group? Proving associativity is trivial in this case, no?

Comment: @user494405 That's the difference between proving that a set with a binary operation is a group, and that a subset of a group is a (sub)group. Associativity and existence of $e$ and inverses you get for free. What you need to show is that the subset is closed under the group law, and that it contains $e$ and the inverses you already know exist. As for commutative, yes, the center is a commutative group. By definition, all elements of the center commutes with all elements of the entire group, including the elements in the center itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by "all elements of the center commutes with all the elements of the entire group"? When you say group here, you mean the group for which the center is a center of, right?

Comment: @user494405 Yes, I mean that all elements of $Z(G)$ commutes with all elements of $G$ (that's the definition of $Z(G)$, after all), so specifically all elements of $Z(G)$ commutes with all elements of $Z(G)$. Sorry I was a bit unclear.

Comment: And what is the significance of this set? It's essentially the part of the group which is commutative, and that's it? Also, if at any point you're getting bored of my obtuseness, don't feel obligated to answer.

Comment: The significance of this set, apart from being a subgroup (and a normal subgroup), comes from the fact that it appears in several theorems, which means that it can be used to obtain results. For instance, I once had an assignment to find all (non-abelian) groups of order $8$ and $12$, and the center was central (heh) to proving that I had found them all.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, thank you very much for taking time to answer all my questions, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

If we're writing primes for inverses, then if $x \in Z(G)$ then $x'g = (g'x)' = (xg')'= gx'$ so $x' \in Z(G)$.

Answer (score 1):

**To see that it is closed:**

let $a, b \in Z(G)$ and show that $ab \in Z(G)$.

To do this, note that for any $g \in G$, we have that $ga=ag$ and $gb=bg$. In other words, since we have inverses:

$gag^{-1}=a$ and $gbg^{-1}=b$.

So, $ab=gag^{-1}gbg^{-1}$. Now use associativity and deduce the result.

**To see inverses:** using the same trick as above, if $gag^{-1}=a$ for all $g \in G$, then $g^{-1}a^{-1}g=a^{-1}$ for  all $g^{-1} \in G$, which is equivalent to all $g \in G$. Note that $a^{-1}$ denotes the usual inverse of $a \in G$.

Comment: You also have to check that $z \in Z(G)$ implies $z^{-1} \in Z(G)$, and this is where the OP claimed to be stuck.

Comment: @fredgoodman. Thank you, I need to read more closely.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in Z(G)$, there is a $x'\in G$ such that $xx'=x'x=e$. So, the problem is to prove that $x'\in Z(G)$. Take $g\in G$. Now, take $g'\in G$ such that $gg'=g'g=e$. Then $xg'=g'x$ (since $x\in Z(G)$), but it follows from this that $gx'=x'g$, as we wanted to prove.